# Pre-loading menus for faster navigation?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm working on a simple (currently only IOS-compatible) application that receives and stores information to and from a database. Right now, whenever I navigate to a menu, I send a request through an ESB to fetch me the data I need to display in the menu. That means that, if I navigate to another menu, and then back to the previous one, I send a new request to the ESB. I do have a method to check if the file is younger than 12 hours old, to reduce the amount of internet traffic.

I was wondering if there was a way to load all menus at once during app launch, and use some kind of property or method to switch between the menus. This would lengthen the startup, but makes for a better and faster use of the app afterwards.

Any advice is truly welcome.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't, but without knowing more about what you are doing it's hard to make any specific suggestions.  Please post the relevant bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like Akavache: https://github.com/akavache/Akavache

That would enable you to cache the data that comes in, and reuse it next time you show the menu.
In your case you could go for this method of Akavache:

```
IObservable<T> GetOrFetchObject<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> fetchFunc, DateTimeOffset? absoluteExpiration = null);
```

It will return your data immediately if available, or fetch it if not.